# Eclipse CDT - how to use an argfile for the linker for a too long command line

Tags: c, windows, eclipse, gcc, linker

I'm using Eclipse CDT 9 Neon with GCC 6.3 on Windows 7 for a STM32 project.

I have installed the GNU ARM Plug-in and use sh.exe for long command line management (cmd.exe from windows have a limite of 8192 char) for calling make.exe (GNU Coreutils date: 04.06.2009).

I'm working on a big project.

Without build exclusion my linker command line is over 33 000 char and generate an error on the linker command line.

With builds exclusions and a reduced version of my project, I have reduce the linker command line to 15 600 char, compilation worked fine and my binary file is operational.

At first, for the full version of my project, the linker command line is bigger than 20 000 char and generate an ACCESS VIOLATION on sh.exe.

With an other version of sh.exe (from Microsemi IDE) I have no more ACCESS VIOLATION on sh.exe and be able to link more file.

But for the full version of my project I have a link error : 
make (e=87): Paramètre incorrect.
This error come from a to long command line (more than 32 000 char).

Other IDE (Winidea with GCC) use an argument file that combine linker file (.ld) and the obj files list to have a very short linker command line.

How can I configure GCC in Eclipse to use an argument file for the linker ?

**I found a solution, not perfect but fully operational. I have writen an bat file to generate obj listing file.**
Instructions to use it are in rem.

I have writen the file "gen__link_ld.bat" :

```
echo off
rem ***************************************************************************
rem Generate script file for the linker to go throuth linker command line too
rem long trouble under windows (32 000 char max)
rem ***************************************************************************
rem Lunch in pre-build step is not advised, this commande is run in paralel
rem with build step that can temporarie supress obj file need to run 
rem compilation a 2nd time to have a script file up to date for the linker.
rem Run in pre-build step generate trouble in debug mode.
rem
rem Use manual lunch with 2 parameters :
rem create a .bat file per build with the folowing commande :
rem gen__link_ld.bat ./project relative path and .ld file name ./project relative build path
rem in linker commande line pattern replace {INPUT}
rem by -Xlinker --script=${ProjDirPath}/${ConfigName}/___link.ld
rem and add manualy librairie after ___link.ld, in this case library include
rem throuth graphical build setting don't work, they may use {INPUT} from the
rem standard commande
rem ***************************************************************************
echo **************************************************************************
echo *****************************                *****************************
echo *****************************     WARNING    *****************************
echo *****************************                *****************************
echo **************************************************************************
echo Generate script file for the linker to go throuth linker command line too
echo long trouble under windows (32 000 char max)
echo 
echo List only existing obj file.
echo The best way is to use manual lunch with one .bat file per build.
echo follow information in r e m above to use it.
echo
echo Run this commande evry time that obj liste is modified.
echo WARNING this function don't delete obj file for file recently exclude
echo frome build.
echo To secure the compilation need a clean to suppress all obj, run a first 
echo build witch compile all file without error (with only linker error) to
echo generate an obj file listing up to date and run a second buid for a 
echo successful linker step. When the OJB file listing is up to date, only 
echo eclipse build commande is needed
echo **************************************************************************
echo Linker file use : %1
echo Build path use : %2
echo **************************************************************************

setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set destination=%2
set destination=%destination:/=\%
rem *** Generate obj file listing ***
echo INPUT(>%destination%\___link.ld
dir %destination%\*.o /s /b >>%destination%\___link.ld
echo )>>%destination%\___link.ld

rem *** Concatenat obj file listing with ld file from parameter 1 ***
set str=%1
set str=%str:/=\%
type %str%>>%destination%\___link.ld
echo *** OBJ file listing up to date
echo **************************************************************************
pause
```

Thanks

Comment: The obvious nonsolution is: instead of linking to individual .o files, create a static library out of them and link to that.

Comment: I feel like you _badly_ need a tool like `make` or `cmake`.

Comment: By using library compilation I will lost debug facility. I could chose witch part of code I want to debug to manage witch part I link as .o and witch part as librairy, but it is not so usefull.

Comment: you can pass the `gcc` link step `ld` a parameter that sets a linker command file.  Then place the actual linker commands in that linker command file.  If the does not work for you,  the `gcc` linker step does allow incremental linking, but I'm not very familiar with it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple workaround I've found for the issue (using a small python script), on the same line of thought of separating the object listing in another file - note that these kind of files are called  *response files* in the GNU world: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Response_Files and they separate the *entire command-line* rather than only the object files and libraries.

Assuming you're using the GNU Make builder+GNU linker:

- You'll need to create a python script and place it somewhere in your project, I'll assume the path to the script is **build/link_with_rsp_file.py**. Place in it the contents below.
- Go to **project properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings**. Make sure the appropriate build configuration is selected. You should find the toolchain settings there.
- Select the linker item. Depending on your build configuration, you should have a Command/Command line pattern pair such as **g++**/**${COMMAND} ${FLAGS} ${OUTPUT_FLAG} ${OUTPUT_PREFIX}${OUTPUT} ${INPUTS}**. We'll assume it looks just like this, adjust accordingly.
- Change the command-line pattern to **@$(file >linkcl.rsp,${FLAGS} ${OUTPUT_FLAG} ${OUTPUT_PREFIX}${OUTPUT} ${INPUTS})python ../build/link_with_rsp_file.py linkcl.rsp ${COMMAND}**. This effectively tells GNU make to take all the linker arguments, put them in the response file linkcl.rsp (using the [$(file)](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Function.html) function) and then run the linker (${COMMAND}) using the generated response file instead.

Python script:

```
import sys, subprocess

def cmd_exec(full_cmd):
    print(full_cmd)
    sys.stdout.flush(); sys.stderr.flush()
    p = subprocess.Popen(full_cmd.split(' '))
    p.communicate()
    return p.returncode == 0

rsp_file, cmd = sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2:]
cmd = ' '.join(cmd)

# First replace all '\' with '/' in the response file (bash doesn't deal well with '\')
with open(rsp_file, "r") as f: linkcl = f.read()
linkcl = linkcl.replace('\\', '/')
with open(rsp_file, "w") as f: f.write(linkcl)

# Call the linker
cmd_exec("{cmd} @{rsp_file}".format(cmd=cmd, rsp_file=rsp_file))
```

Comment: 1. "c/c++ build -> builder -> builder type" should be "External builder" (in fact, using "make");
2. When I modified the linker command line pattern, eclipse doesn't generate "Debug/objects.mk", but "Debug/makefile" requires the output target depends on it, so I have to add the file manually

Answer (score 0):

I've improved the way in https://stackoverflow.com/a/61644057/5789722 :

1. Go to `project properties` -> `C/C++ Build`, and ensure `Builder type` is `External builder` and enable `Generate Makefiles automatically`
2. Go to `project properties` -> `C/C++ Build` -> `Settings`, select `Tool Settings` -> a linker like `Cygwin C++ Linker`
3. fill `Command line pattern` with:

```
@$(file >linkcl.rsp,$(subst \,/,${FLAGS}) ${OUTPUT_FLAG} ${OUTPUT_PREFIX}${OUTPUT} ${INPUTS}) ${COMMAND} @linkcl.rsp
```

- 1. here I use [`subst`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html) to replace `\` with `/`, then `link_with_rsp_file.py` is not needed any more